# Should calculating probability for a specific situation be closed because of a canonical answer?

Tags: discussion

There is a VTC on this
[AA versus AA what is the chance of winning](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/8920/aa-versus-aa-what-is-the-chance-of-winning)

To me many of the users on this site are not able to calculate probability even with instructions.  If I did not know how already I would not be able to do it with those instructions.  To me that is not even a good canonical answer.
 [calculate probabilities](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/8077/how-do-i-calculate-poker-hand-probabilities)

This site does not even close question on counting outs which to me is much easier.

I get the site often closes a which hand wins because of the canonical answer but I would expect most if not all users to understand that answer.  They need to understand that answer to play poker.  [How to determine the winning hands in poker?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6680/how-to-determine-the-winning-hands-in-poker)

Also related:

[Who wins this hand](https://poker.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248/who-wins-this-hand).

[How do I calculate the odds of making a four of a kind by the river given I have a pair?](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4300/how-do-i-calculate-the-odds-of-making-a-four-of-a-kind-by-the-river-given-i-have/8483#8483)

Answer (score 1):

In some ways I agree with you that a question which is just an example of how to calculate odds is something that can be conceptualised and thus is likely to be duplicated often. Maybe there is a case for closing these "duplicates" and pointing at other Q's that can explain all possible cases.

That said, nuances of these questions draw in new users as they search for common situations that they face, rather than search using more abstract representations of the underlying principle. At least at first.

Unless the questions are voted down significantly (which I think users currently use too little, rather than Vote-To-Close), I'm inclined to leave them up and available for the time being. As the site grows, I expect these Q's will be edited and honed to perfection. Alas, that takes time.

As a longer term expectation, I see the site gradually moving in that direction. A good example is actually a question you mention ("How to determine the winning hands in poker?"), which if I remember correctly wasn't the original first choice for re-directions pertaining to that problem, but it has evolved to be.

My best current suggestion is to improve on the question and answer (via editing or new Q+A's), and allow the site to decide if it's useful enough to re-direct other Q's to it.

Comment: Maybe I was not clear but I think a canonical answer on probability is too much for this site.  This site does not even support Latex.  My request to add Latex has been deleted.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Perhaps it is. Time will tell.